# How to store, manage REST API JWT authentication token in vue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, jwt, axios

I am a noob, using vue.js and a node auth api, the api works fine and provides the jwt token in the response, my question is how can i use the token in all the requests that follows (using axios), and any best practices for handling the token in the front end is also appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you should save token in local storage and send it with every request

Comment: Show your work?

Comment: `methods: {
      login(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let currentObj = this
        this.axios.post('http://localhost:3600/auth', {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            // how to store the token after this???
            currentObj.output = response.data
            console.log(currentObj.output)
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            currentObj.output = error
            console.log(currentObj.output)
          })
      }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](https://github.com/mazdok/beauty-vuejs-boilerplate) a lot of good patterns which I personally use on my projects and how also JWT token handling.

For saving token in a brower, you can use cookie, sessionStorage or localStorate, last one is the most popular now (short explination [here](https://scotch.io/@PratyushB/local-storage-vs-session-storage-vs-cookie)).

In a few words, you can create an axion instance and add a token before request sent.

```
const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_SERVER_API,
  // here you can specify other params 
})

http.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  // Do something before request is sent
  request.headers['Authorization'] = `JWT ${TOKEN_HERE}`
  // some logic what to do if toke invalid, etc ...
  return request
}, function (error) {
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

Comment: So localStorage is ok to use?, i found some posts that says otherwsie

Comment: Yes, that's normal. Sometimes it's better to use sessionStorage, it depends on your case.

Comment: Where does `${TOKEN_HERE}` come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that for Your scenario in your vuejs app.

```
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'

const securedAxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

const plainAxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

securedAxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  const method = config.method.toUpperCase()
  if (method !== 'OPTIONS' && method !== 'GET') {
    config.headers = {
      ...config.headers,
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': localStorage.csrf
    }
  }
  return config
})

securedAxiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(null, error => {
  if (
    error.response &&
    error.response.config &&
    error.response.status === 401
  ) {
    return plainAxiosInstance
      .post('/refresh', {}, { headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': localStorage.csrf } })
      .then(response => {
        localStorage.csrf = response.data.csrf
        localStorage.signedIn = true

        let retryConfig = error.response.config
        retryConfig.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = localStorage.csrf
        return plainAxiosInstance.request(retryConfig)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        delete localStorage.csrf
        delete localStorage.signedIn

        location.replace('/')
        return Promise.reject(error)
      })
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
})

export { securedAxiosInstance, plainAxiosInstance }
```

And in your component you use this to process your request with api

> Products.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'products',
  data () {
    return {
      products: [],
      newProduct: [],
      error: '',
      editedProduct: ''
    }
  },
  created () {
    if (!localStorage.signedIn) {
      this.$router.replace('/')
    } else {
      this.$http.secured.get('/api/v1/products')
        .then(response => { this.products = response.data })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, 'Something went wrong'))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setError (error, text) {
      this.error = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error) || text
    },
    addProduct () {
      const value = this.newProduct
      if (!value) {
        return
      }
      this.$http.secured.post('/api/v1/products/', { product: { name: this.newProduct.name } })
        .then(response => {
          this.products.push(response.data)
          this.newProduct = ''
        })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, 'Cannot create product'))
    },
    removeProduct (product) {
      this.$http.secured.delete(`/api/v1/products/${product.id}`)
        .then(response => {
          this.products.splice(this.products.indexOf(product), 1)
        })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, 'Cannot delete product'))
    },
    editProduct (product) {
      this.editedproduct = product
    },
    updateProduct (product) {
      this.editedProduct = ''
      this.$http.secured.patch(`/api/v1/products/${product.id}`, { product: { title: product.name } })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, 'Cannot update product'))
    }
  }
}
```